# Laravel 10 CI/CD test fails with SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, phpunit, github-actions, cicd, laravel-10

I want to make an automation for the test check when I push into main branches

I've created this github workflow

```yaml
name: Run tests

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - develop

jobs:
  tests:
    name: Run tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '8.2'
          extensions: dom, curl, libxml, mbstring, zip, pcntl, pdo, sqlite, pdo_sqlite, bcmath, soap, intl, gd, exif, iconv
          coverage: none

      - uses: mirromutth/mysql-action@v1.1
        with:
          mysql database: db-testing
          mysql user: root
          mysql password: test

      - name: Run composer install
        run: composer install -n --prefer-dist

      - name: Prepare Laravel Application
        run: |
          cp .env.example .env
          cp .env.ci .env.testing
          php artisan optimize:clear
          php artisan key:generate

      - name: Run tests
        run: php artisan test
```

my env.ci file looks like this:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=testing
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db-testing
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=test

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailpit
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

I tested my application in my local machine it worked, but in the github action I get this error message for every test:

[image: error]

I tried to use sqlite but I want to test it on mysql, because it's the prod env.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hey there, did you finally find the issue?